# Thresholds in Social Proof

Tags: social, social-proof

When using a social proof element like this example ("502 people find it helpful"), is it taboo to hide the element until it reaches a certain number of votes?

If it is ok to do this, is there some value with which it becomes motivating? I can understand seeing "" but if it is helpful if it says 10? or 50? etc.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not taboo to hide the element until it receives a certain amount of votes – Reddit hides votes on new posts, as an example, to encourage users to cast votes independently and avoid a bandwagon effect.

Social proof helps assure users that they're making the right decision. I think in your case, users are voting on whether something is *useful*, vs. *popular*. The lack of usefulness is helpful information as well, so it's a better user experience to not hide the element at all. The default can be "Be the first to vote" and then you show the vote starting at 1. You'll want to put the date of the question fairly close by, so users can determine if the lack of usefulness is related to how new the question is, or if it's truly not interesting to your community.